# SQL function to populate a simple date table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to populate a table with simple (Year, month, days) columns for upto 10 years and I am roughly taking every month to have 30 days.It looks like as below.

I have written the below code to populate the table but I have error on the second 'while' it say 'Expecting '(',or select'. Any clue why?

[Simple Date table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXEre.png)

```
 declare @month varchar(20)
    set @month ='1'

    declare @day varchar(20)
    set @day='1'

    declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
    while(@Year <=10)
     (
      while(@month<=12)
        ( 
          while(@day<= @day+30)
              (
               insert into simple_table values(@Year,@month,@day)
          @day=@day+1 
       )
              @month+1
       )
       @year = @year+1
       )
       )
```

Comment: you are having one extra `)`

Comment: `while(@day<= @day+30)` will always be true....

Comment: @TheGameiswar, Ah! I removed the last extra ) still I have the same error.

Comment: Also, this is not proper t-sql syntax. code blocks are marked with `begin...end`, and setting variables is done using `set` or `select`. Another thing is that using loops is probably not the best way to do it. Using a numbers table is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of an **ad-hoc tally table** and a **Cross Join** (or two)

Your sample was a little unclear.  This assumes the Day column is not 1-30 but 1-3600 for 10 years.  I'm assuming you are building some sort of amortization schedule of 30/360

```
Select Year = 'Year'+cast(Y as varchar(25))
      ,Month = M
      ,Day   = Row_Number() over (Order by Y,M,D)
 From  (Select Top (10) Y=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From  master..spt_values) Y
 Cross Join (Select Top (12) M=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From  master..spt_values) M
 Cross Join (Select Top (30) D=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From  master..spt_values) D
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, John. I could have never come up with this solution. This is exactly what I needed. I think we can do with 360 days per year.

Comment: @SKa happy it helped. Two things.  1) Never is a big word  2) Try to think data-sets and not linear processing in SQL.

Comment: @SKa Small tweak for actual days per month and/or year   Just let me know

Comment: :-) I am yet to understand how this piece of code works. I have a deadline looming and this was very helpful to get it done quickly. Once this slight rush is over, I plan to come back to this and understand the workings first and then it was on my mind to see if I could do some tweaks on my own first. Very nice of you. :)Thank You. I might get ack to you again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it would be a lot easier to use one loop instead of 3.

```
Declare @D DateTime;

Set @D = GetDate();

while @D < DateAdd(Year, 10, GetDate())
    Begin

        Insert Into simple_table(Year, Month, Day) Select Year(@D), Month(@D), Day(@D)

        Set @D = DateAdd(Day, 1, @D)

    End
```

Basically, just use a date as your loop variable, increment one day each time through the loop.  Additional benefit, you get exactly the right number of days in each month (including leap years).

Comment: Thanks, @G Mastros. I needed a general table. This is a good piece of code if I needed to generate a date table for a given year.